# How can I deal with "LifecycleOwner" error in android studio 3.0.1?

Tags: android

I have imported an old version project(android studio 2.3.3) in android studio 3.0.1.
When I build this project,  I get this error.
[image]

I have been trying to fix this error for several days but I can't deal with that.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try to change `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` to latest version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` and check..

Comment: wow! thanks. it works well.

Comment: welcome @VitalyKrapauskas. Happy to help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line:

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`

to

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.+
```

Comment: that's great happy coding :)